# RSpec matcher that checks collection to include item that satisfies lambda

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am a bit at a loss as to how to write a RSpec 3.2.x spec that checks wether a list contains at least one item that satisfies a condition.

Here is an example:

```
model = Invoice.new
model.name = 'test'
changes = model.changes
expect(changes).to include { |x| x.key == 'name' && x.value == 'test' }
```

There will be other (automated) changes in the changes list too so I don't want to verify that there is only one specific change and I also don't want to rely on ordering `expect(changes.first)...` so I basically need a way to specify that at least one change in the list satisfies the condition.

I could do something like this:

```
result = changes.any? { |x| x.key == 'name' .. }
expect(result).to eq(true)
```

But then the rspec failure would not give me any meaningful output so I thought there must be a built-in way to match this.

Any other suggestions on how to structure the test are also welcome.

Edit: To be clear - the changes are a list of ChangeObject so I need to access their `.key` and `.value` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RSpec 3, [matchers are fully composable](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers/), which means you can pass any object which implements Ruby's `===` protocol (including a matcher!) to `include` and it will work properly.  Lambdas in Ruby 1.9 implement the `===` protocol, which means you can do this:

```
expect(changes).to include(lambda { |x| x.key == 'name' && value == 'test' })
```

That said, that's not going to give you a great failure message (since RSpec has no way to generate a description of the lambda).  I'm not sure where `value` comes from in your example, but if it is intended to be `x.value`, you could use the `have_attributes` (or `an_object_having_attributes` for better readability) matcher:

```
expect(changes).to include an_object_having_attributes(key: 'name', value: 'test')
```

Comment: That's excellent. I didn't know about `an_object_having_attributes`. Thank you!

Comment: It's an alias of `have_attributes`, a new matcher introduced in RSpec 3.1: http://rspec.info/blog/2014/09/rspec-3-1-has-been-released/#expectations-new-haveattributes-matcher

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
expect(changes).to be_any{ |x| //logic to match }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work since it's no hash but a Object. I will clarify the question

Comment: I also can't check for equality of the matching object since the object is constructed inside the class and I don't want to break visibility rules.

Comment: In that case  "expect(changes).to be_include { |x| x.key == 'name' && value == 'test' }" would do the job

Comment: `be_include` throws an argument error but you pointed me in the right direction. `be_any { |x| .. }` solved the issue for me. Please update the answer so I can mark it as accepted